# JPA potential Sync Issue

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

In my lodger class, i have

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "lodger", orphanRemoval=true)
//  @JsonBackReference
private List<RoomPayment> roomPaymentList;
```

In my RoomPayment class i have

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "lodger_id")
private Lodger lodger;
```

Actually i do

```
@Override
public Long save(RoomPaymentDto roomPaymentDto) {

    RoomPayment roomPayment;

    if (roomPaymentDto.getRoomPaymentId() != null) {
        roomPayment = repository.findOne(roomPaymentDto.getRoomPaymentId());
    } else {
        roomPayment = new RoomPayment();
    }

    MapperFactory mapperFactory = new DefaultMapperFactory.Builder().build();
    mapperFactory.classMap(RoomPayment.class, RoomPaymentDto.class).byDefault().register();

    MapperFacade mapper = mapperFactory.getMapperFacade();

    mapper.map(roomPaymentDto, roomPayment);

    repository.save(roomPayment);

    return roomPayment.getRoomPayementId();
}
```

In this method, do i need to get the Lodger and assign it to roomPayment?

Answer (score 0):

No, if the dto contains the right `Lodger` of course.

The point is that there are no cascades from `RoomPayment` to the associated `Lodger`, meaning that Hibernate will not complain about the detached object when you save the `roomPayment`.

Hibernate will just take the id from the `lodger` instance which it will use to maintain the association (because `RoomPayment` is the owner of the association).

Comment: my dto contain only lodger id. Because i use mappedBy on lodger, is it a error to save  roomPayment by itselft instead of passed by lodger?

Comment: No, because your intention is not to update the `logder` anyway (`roomPayment` remains associated with whatever `Lodger` it contained before the update).

Comment: on the web, i see then people who use mappedBy like me save the kid via the parent.... so for me it's it usefull to keep mappedBy?

Comment: `mappedBy` has absolutely nothing to do with your issue. You should keep it of course, since the association is bidirectional.

Comment: so i can remove also the cascade in lodger

Comment: No, you don't have to. It has also nothing to do with your use case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90039/discussion-between-robert-trudel-and-dragan-bozanovic).

Comment: cascade persist is usefull i think only if i want to persist automaticaly roomPayment when i persis lodger. so if i don't pass by lodger to save roomPayment that seem useless for me